# creating ListBoxItems with custom style in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem, custom-element

This may seem familiar to you but I have a problem creating a custom List Box with custom style as well. I can only do one of them at the same time... I can't use both. and another thing is that could you tell me how to add the **custom** `listboxitem` in c# code so I could easily add it to the program?
what I mean is that for example if you put an image before the text of `listboxitem` and then give it an style, but all thease must be done for all items.

thanks to all

Comment: You'd better to read some docs before, try to use Template

Comment: I don't have time reading anything for now... that's why I asked this question...thanks

Comment: "I don't have time reading anything for now... that's why I asked this question" You shouldn't say that too loud here on StackOverflow. We're not here to do your work. Instead we're expecting that you do some own research before asking. Please take a look at the [SO Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what have you already tried out? Are you expecting SO users do the work for you?

Listbox tag has a ListboxItemTemplate. For that you can implement a DataTemplate has a StaticResource and  put whatever you want inside.

Check the documentation on MSDN.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. And you should have downvoted and close-voted the question.